# How to create a meter whose value changes with change in value of range slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, meter

I am  beginner in HTML, CSS and JavaScript
[The meter I have to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD3u6.jpg) .
I got a task to create a speedometer whose value changes with the changes in range slider.

I just want to know the basic idea of how to create this. Please help me

Comment: Stackoverflow isnt a free code writing service, can you show your attempts or your code that you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You have already know CSS, HTML, and javascript. That's good.
If you want to create your meter, I encourage you to learn SVG.

> Here is a good meter demo for it.
> https://hongkiat.github.io/svg-meter-gauge/
> You can scroll the x-axis scrolling bar to play it.

*For your purpose of making your meter,

I would like to suggest the following three steps for you to make your meter.*

**Step 1. learn SVG**
Here is a good start to learn some knowledge of SVG.
https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp
You cannot create a meter without any basic knowledge of SVG.

**Step 2. learn how other people make a meter**
And for your purpose, I think the following article is good for you.
https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/svg-meter-gauge-tutorial/
This article shows you how to make a meter from zero.
You can follow this article to make the same thing.

**Step 3. Make your meter**
After Step 1 and Step 2, you have enough concept and idea to make your own meter.